# Scaling Nuclio With KEDA Based on Queue Length: Error ScaledObject Name is Not Specified

Tags: rabbitmq, serverless, minikube, keda, nuclio

I have a nuclio serverless function (deployed in minikube) that gets triggered by messages in RabbitMQ's queue. From what I know, nuclio scales based on CPU metrics and I wanted to scale it based on the queue's length using KEDA. Unfortunately, the scaling did not work, and when I check the keda-operator-metrics-apiserver, I get a "scaledObject name is not specified" error:

```
kubectl logs -l app=keda-operator-metrics-apiserver -n keda

E0322 18:06:25.317354       1 provider.go:103] keda_metrics_adapter/provider "msg"="please specify scaledObject name, it needs to be set as value of label selector \"scaledobject.keda.sh/name\" on the query" "error"="scaledObject name is not specified"
E0322 18:06:25.321840       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"scaledObject name is not specified"}: scaledObject name is not specified
E0322 18:07:59.165516       1 provider.go:103] keda_metrics_adapter/provider "msg"="please specify scaledObject name, it needs to be set as value of label selector \"scaledobject.keda.sh/name\" on the query" "error"="scaledObject name is not specified"
E0322 18:07:59.165559       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"scaledObject name is not specified"}: scaledObject name is not specified
```

This is the configuration file for my nuclio serverless function:

```
apiVersion: nuclio.io/v1
kind: NuclioFunction
metadata:
  name: nuc-handler
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  handler: "nuc-handler:NuclioHandler"
  runtime: "golang"
  build:
    path: . 
  minReplicas: 1
  triggers:
    myRabbitMQTopic:
      kind: "rabbit-mq"
      url: "amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local:5672/"
      attributes:
        exchangeName: ""
        queueName: subPopQueue
        maxWorkers: 1
```

Also, more information I pulled from nuclio's dashboard about the serverless function:

```
metadata:
  name: nuc-handler
  labels:
    nuclio.io/project-name: default
  resourceVersion: "1073643"
spec:
  handler: "nuc-handler:NuclioHandler"
  runtime: golang
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 25m
      memory: 1Mi
  image: "docker.io/arthurmerlin/processor-nuc-handler:latest"
  imageHash: "1710788017019969350"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 1
  targetCPU: 75
  triggers:
    default-http:
      class: ""
      kind: http
      name: default-http
      maxWorkers: 1
      attributes:
        serviceType: ClusterIP
    myRabbitMQTopic:
      class: ""
      kind: rabbit-mq
      name: myRabbitMQTopic
      url: "amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local:5672/"
      attributes:
        exchangeName: ""
        maxWorkers: 1
        queueName: subPopQueue
  version: -1
  alias: latest
  build:
    functionConfigPath: functionconfig.yaml
    registry: docker.io/arthurmerlin
    codeEntryType: image
    timestamp: 1710788173
    image: ""
    noCache: false
    offline: false
    dependencies: []
    runtimeAttributes:
      repositories: []
  runRegistry: docker.io/arthurmerlin
  platform: {}
  readinessTimeoutSeconds: 120
  securityContext: {}
  disableDefaultHTTPTrigger: false
  eventTimeout: ""
  waitReadinessTimeoutBeforeFailure: false
```

This is the keda ScaledObject configuration file:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: nuclio-nuc-handler
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment 
    name: nuclio-nuc-handler
  pollingInterval: 1 
  cooldownPeriod: 30 
  minReplicaCount: 1  
  maxReplicaCount: 30 
  triggers:
  - type: rabbitmq
    metadata:
      queueName: subPopQueue 
      host: amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local:5672/
      mode: QueueLength
      value: "1"
```

And here's the description of the ScaledObject:

```
kubectl describe ScaledObject -n nuclio

Name:         nuclio-nuc-handler
Namespace:    nuclio
Labels:       scaledobject.keda.sh/name=nuclio-nuc-handler
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  keda.sh/v1alpha1
Kind:         ScaledObject
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-03-22T19:08:31Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.keda.sh
  Generation:        1
  Resource Version:  1218243
  UID:               6212e530-ce47-49be-99b2-f308c0e8f909
Spec:
  Cooldown Period:    30
  Max Replica Count:  30
  Min Replica Count:  1
  Polling Interval:   1
  Scale Target Ref:
    Kind:  Deployment
    Name:  nuclio-nuc-handler
  Triggers:
    Metadata:
      Host:        amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local:5672/
      Mode:        QueueLength
      Protocol:    amqp
      Queue Name:  subPopQueue
      Value:       1
    Type:          rabbitmq
Status:
  Conditions:
    Message:  ScaledObject is defined correctly and is ready for scaling
    Reason:   ScaledObjectReady
    Status:   True
    Type:     Ready
    Message:  Scaling is not performed because triggers are not active
    Reason:   ScalerNotActive
    Status:   False
    Type:     Active
    Message:  No fallbacks are active on this scaled object
    Reason:   NoFallbackFound
    Status:   False
    Type:     Fallback
    Status:   Unknown
    Type:     Paused
  External Metric Names:
    s0-rabbitmq-subPopQueue
  Health:
    s0-rabbitmq-subPopQueue:
      Number Of Failures:  0
      Status:              Happy
  Hpa Name:                keda-hpa-nuclio-nuc-handler
  Original Replica Count:  1
  Scale Target GVKR:
    Group:            apps
    Kind:             Deployment
    Resource:         deployments
    Version:          v1
  Scale Target Kind:  apps/v1.Deployment
Events:
  Type    Reason              Age   From           Message
  ----    ------              ----  ----           -------
  Normal  KEDAScalersStarted  84s   keda-operator  Scaler rabbitmq is built.
  Normal  KEDAScalersStarted  84s   keda-operator  Started scalers watch
```

kubectl client version: v1.29.1
kubectl kustomize version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
kubectl server version: v1.28.3

nuctl client version:
"Label: 1.12.14, Git commit: 4d67f0d79e6008523e9a540c01f90ccde7357e44, OS: linux, Arch: amd64, Go version: go1.21.0"

RabbitMQ's chart: rabbitmq-12.14.0
RabbitMQ's APP version: 3.12.13

This is my first time using these tools (Kubernetes, configuring files, Serverless, etc.). If there's a ridiculously obvious mistake somewhere, I apologize. I also haven't seen examples of nuclio serverless functions being used with KEDA, so I'm not sure if KEDA works with nuclio..? I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.